# Arithmetic mean with immutable list

Tags: javascript

I have an array that calculates the arithmetic mean of the numbers in the array.
I know how to do with a regular array and I know how to do with the Immutable list.
Tell me how to calculate the average arithmetic array through an Immutable list does not use my example via a reduce.

common array

```js
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function mean(numbers) {

  let total = 0,
    i;

  for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i += 1) {
    total += numbers[i];
  }
  return total / numbers.length;
}

console.log(mean(numbers));
```

immutable list

```
function sum(collection) {
  return collection.reduce((sum, x) => sum + x, 0)
}

List([ 1,2,3,4 ])
  .filter(x => x % 2 === 0)
  .update(sum)
```

I'm just learning, I really hope for your third option.

Comment: Why have you added typescript, redux, and immutable.js tags?

Comment: Studies maybe, but I believe the question is not.

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I have no idea what you're asking here. So you know how to calculate the mean, but you don't want to calculate it the way you already know how to do it?

Comment: do the same thing as in the second example, using the first example. An example with an ordinary array is to make it iimmutable.

Comment: @andre So you want to use a `for` loop to calculate the total of an immutable list? Why?

Comment: It is not necessary to use for. The main thing is not to use the syntax of the immunabul.Js and reduce. I was told that this is a date for me to deal with the immutable list, how it works, because reduce its an easy way.